# display number of visits per month this year

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I want to display total number of visits per month this year . But the following query returns error code of missing expression. What have i missed?

```
 SELECT CASE 
     WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '),     'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 1 THEN 'January '
     WHEN extract(month from date  TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '),   'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 2 THEN 'February'
WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 3 THEN 'March'
WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 4 THEN 'April'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 5 THEN 'May'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 6 THEN 'June'
WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 7 THEN 'July'
WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 8 THEN 'August'
WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 9 THEN 'September'
WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 10 THEN 'October'   
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 11 THEN 'November'   
 ELSE 'December'
    END AS "Month " , 
    COUNT(*) AS "Number of visits"
 FROM allrecord where  extract(year from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')= extract(year from date sysdate) 
 GROUP BY CASE 
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 1 THEN 'January '
     WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 2 THEN 'February'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 3 THEN 'March'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 4 THEN 'April'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 5 THEN 'May'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 6 THEN 'June'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 7 THEN 'July'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 8 THEN 'August'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 9 THEN 'September'
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 10 THEN 'October'   
 WHEN extract(month from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')  = 11 THEN 'November'   

       ELSE 'December'
          END;
```

An extra question to ask , I am creating a application using ORacle application builder . But after I created a page and want to edit the records in the form , an error message shows that data can be be fetched . What does it mean? Any steps I missed?

Comment: My experience with Oracle is almost none, but as I understand it you could use `TO_CHAR(visit_time, 'MONTH')` instead of this cumbersome case statement?

Comment: For your extra question on Oracle Application Builder you might want to ask it separately and give more details on the error you get.

Answer (score 4):

This query can all be condensed down to:

```
  select to_char(VISIT_TIME, 'fmMonth') as "Month"
        ,count(*) as "Number of Visits"
    from ALLRECORD
   where extract(year from VISIT_TIME) = extract(year from sysdate)
group by to_char(VISIT_TIME, 'fmMonth');
```

The missing expression error will have come from putting the keyword `date` in front of the `to_date` in the `extract` functions. It is unnecessary. You would either use:

```
select extract (year from date '2011-01-01') from sys.dual
```

or:

```
select extract (year from to_date('2011-01-01')) from sys.dual
```

But never:

```
select extract (year from date to_date('2011-01-01')) from sys.dual
```

Comment: what i didn't mention is visit_time is a timestamp

Comment: That's fine, `to_char`, `to_date`, `extract`, etc. all work on `timestamp` types.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Oracle have a function to extract a monthname from a date like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(visit_time 'MONTH') as month
COUNT(*) AS "Number of visits"
FROM allrecord 
WHERE  extract(year from date TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (visit_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy '), 'mm/dd/yyyy')= extract(year from date sysdate) 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(visit_time 'MONTH')
```